# How to build a pipeline finding the best preprocessing per column in a fine-grained fashion?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

In sklearn we can use the column transformer within a pipeline to apply a preprocessing choice to specific columns like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MaxAbsScaler, MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler, ...
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer, make_column_transformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# this is my x_data
x_data = pd.DataFrame(..., columns=['Variable1', 'Variable2', 'Variable3'])

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessing1', make_column_transformer((StandardScaler(), ['Variable1']),
                                                                       remainder='passthrough')),
                           ('preprocessing2', make_column_transformer((MaxAbsScaler(), ['Variable2']),
                                                                       remainder='passthrough')),
                           ('preprocessing3', make_column_transformer((MinMaxScaler(), ['Variable3']),
                                                                       remainder='passthrough')),
                           ('clf', MLPClassifier(...)
                          ]
                   )
```

then we would run the GridSearchCV something along the lines of the following:

```
params = [{'preprocessing1': [MinMaxScaler(), MaxAbsScaler(), StandardScaler()], # <<<<<<<<<<<<< How???
           'preprocessing2': [MinMaxScaler(), MaxAbsScaler(), StandardScaler()], # <<<<<<<<<<<<< How???
           'preprocessing3': [MinMaxScaler(), MaxAbsScaler(), StandardScaler()], # <<<<<<<<<<<<< How???
           'ann__hidden_layer_sizes': [(100,), (200,)],
           'ann__solver': ['adam', 'lbfs', 'sgd'],
            ...
          }]

cv = GridSearch(pipeline, params, cv=10, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1, refit=True)
```

What I would like to do, is to find the best preprocessing *per predictor* because usually one preprocessing for all predictors doesn't work best.

Comment: Why not just one `ColumnTransformer`, if you apply different scalers to different columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming convention in a pipeline is using double underscore `__` to separate steps, and their parameters.

You can see the different parameter of your pipeline and their value using `pipeline.get_params()`.

In your case the parameter `preprocessing1__standardscaler` is referencing the scaling preprocessing defined for the first step of your pipeline and this is the argument that should be set during the `GridSearchCV`.

The example below illustrates how to perform this operation:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, MaxAbsScaler
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

X, y = make_classification(
    n_features=3, n_informative=3, n_redundant=0, random_state=42
)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("preprocessing1", make_column_transformer((StandardScaler(), [0]), remainder="passthrough")),
        ("preprocessing2", make_column_transformer((StandardScaler(), [1]), remainder="passthrough")),
        ("preprocessing3", make_column_transformer((StandardScaler(), [2]), remainder="passthrough")),
        ("clf", MLPClassifier()),
    ]
)

param_grid = {
    "preprocessing1__standardscaler": [StandardScaler(), MinMaxScaler(), MaxAbsScaler()],
    "preprocessing2__standardscaler": [StandardScaler(), MinMaxScaler(), MaxAbsScaler()],
    "preprocessing3__standardscaler": [StandardScaler(), MinMaxScaler(), MaxAbsScaler()],
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv=10, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)
grid_search.fit(X, y)
grid_search.best_params_
```

This will return the following output:

```
{'preprocessing1__standardscaler': MinMaxScaler(),
 'preprocessing2__standardscaler': StandardScaler(),
 'preprocessing3__standardscaler': MaxAbsScaler()}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! great answer! it is a pity that the column transformer needs to be accessed by the default scaler `__standardscaler` and not by a generic neutral form ... cosmetics but ok.

Comment: You're welcome :) I think that this was implemented to ensure that every preprocessor,  estimator and hyperparameters have a unique key inside the pipeline.

Comment: @SkyWalker You could use the full `ColumnTransformer` instead of `make_column_transformer`, in which case you can at least specify your own (shorter) name for the transformer.